# page width table in latex

Tags: tables

I have two identical tables and I want them to be a page width long, many thanks in advance.

```
\documentclass[11pt,authoryear,sort&compress]{report}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabulary,array,tabularx}
\usepackage{geometry}

\newcolumntype{z}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}
    
    
\begin{table}[!ht]
    \centering
    \footnotesize
    \begin{tabularx}{1\textwidth}{rlrrrrrrrr}
        \toprule
        & Country & Article.No. & \%Freq & SCP & \%SCP & MCP & \%MCP & TGC & TGC/t \\  
        \midrule
        1 & USA             &  78 & 22.16 &  55 & 22.73 &  23 & 20.91 & 3057 & 39.19 \\ 
        2 & China           &  42 & 11.93 &  32 & 13.22 &  10 & 9.09 & 438 & 10.43 \\ 
        3 & United Kingdom  &  28 & 7.95 &  17 & 7.02 &  11 & 10.00 & 410 & 14.64 \\ 
        4 & India           &  17 & 4.83 &  16 & 6.61 &   1 & 0.91 & 156 & 9.18 \\ 
        5 & Italy           &  12 & 3.41 &   9 & 3.72 &   3 & 2.73 &  74 & 6.17 \\ 
        6 & Australia       &  11 & 3.12 &   6 & 2.48 &   5 & 4.55 &  83 & 7.54 \\ 
        7 & South Africa    &  10 & 2.84 &   8 & 3.31 &   2 & 1.82 &  16 & 1.60 \\ 
        8 & Ghana           &   9 & 2.56 &   9 & 3.72 &   0 & 0.00 &  69 & 7.67 \\ 
        9 & Germany         &   8 & 2.27 &   4 & 1.65 &   4 & 3.64 & 323 & 40.38 \\ 
        10 & Vietnam         &   8 & 2.27 &   4 & 1.65 &   4 & 3.64 &  16 & 2.00 \\ 
        \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
    \caption{The most influential countries, sorted based on total number of Article.No. %\\\hspace{\textwidth}
        Note:  \%Freq,  \%SCP, and \%MCP are the percentage of the total  Article.No., SCP, and MCP, respectively.}  %he total number published articles
    %\label{tab:Most-Cited-Countries}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[!ht]
    \centering
    \footnotesize
    \begin{tabularx}{1\textwidth}{rllrrrrr}
        \toprule
        & Affiliation & Country & Article.No. & TLC & TLC/t & TGC & TGC/t \\  
        \midrule
        1 & World Bank &     USA              & 16 &  61 & 6.28 & 819 & 77.17 \\ 
        2 & Int Monetary Fund &   USA       &3 &  32 & 3.09 & 454 & 35.94 \\  
        3 & Dartmouth Coll & USA            &1 &  29 & 1.61 & 224 & 12.44 \\ 
        4 & Tilburg Univ &     Netherlands  & 2 &  29 & 3.00 & 135 & 12.98 \\
        5 & Wellesley Coll &    USA          &1 &  29 & 1.61 & 224 & 12.44 \\ 
        6 & Univ Amsterdam &   Netherlands   & 2 &  25 & 1.92 & 479 & 38.11 \\
        7 & Univ Kansas &     USA             & 2 &  22 & 2.60 &  56 & 6.61 \\  
        8 & Harvard Univ &   USA           &2 &  17 & 2.05 & 101 & 11.05 \\ 
        9 & Univ Warwick &     UK           &5 &  17 & 1.46 & 128 & 11.68 \\ 
        10 & Univ Copenhagen &   Denmark          &  4 &  16 & 1.93 &  63 & 7.14 \\  
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    \caption{The most influential affiliations, sorted based on TLC.} %the total number
%   \label{tab:Most-Cited-Affliations}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `tabularx`, I'd recommend using `tabular*` in combination with `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}`. Since `\footnotesize` is quite small and both tabes easily fit into the available space with a larger font size such as `\small`, you might want to consider replacing `\footnotesize` with `\small`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,authoryear,sort&compress]{report}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{geometry}


\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
    
    
\begin{table}[!ht]
    \footnotesize
    \begin{tabular*}{1\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}rlrrrrrrrr}
        \toprule
        & Country & Article.No. & \%Freq & SCP & \%SCP & MCP & \%MCP & TGC & TGC/t \\  
        \midrule
        1 & USA             &  78 & 22.16 &  55 & 22.73 &  23 & 20.91 & 3057 & 39.19 \\ 
        2 & China           &  42 & 11.93 &  32 & 13.22 &  10 & 9.09 & 438 & 10.43 \\ 
        3 & United Kingdom  &  28 & 7.95 &  17 & 7.02 &  11 & 10.00 & 410 & 14.64 \\ 
        4 & India           &  17 & 4.83 &  16 & 6.61 &   1 & 0.91 & 156 & 9.18 \\ 
        5 & Italy           &  12 & 3.41 &   9 & 3.72 &   3 & 2.73 &  74 & 6.17 \\ 
        6 & Australia       &  11 & 3.12 &   6 & 2.48 &   5 & 4.55 &  83 & 7.54 \\ 
        7 & South Africa    &  10 & 2.84 &   8 & 3.31 &   2 & 1.82 &  16 & 1.60 \\ 
        8 & Ghana           &   9 & 2.56 &   9 & 3.72 &   0 & 0.00 &  69 & 7.67 \\ 
        9 & Germany         &   8 & 2.27 &   4 & 1.65 &   4 & 3.64 & 323 & 40.38 \\ 
        10 & Vietnam         &   8 & 2.27 &   4 & 1.65 &   4 & 3.64 &  16 & 2.00 \\ 
        \bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
    \caption{The most influential countries, sorted based on total number of Article.No. %\\\hspace{\textwidth}
        Note:  \%Freq,  \%SCP, and \%MCP are the percentage of the total  Article.No., SCP, and MCP, respectively.}  %he total number published articles
    %\label{tab:Most-Cited-Countries}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[!ht]
    \footnotesize
    \begin{tabular*}{1\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}rllrrrrr}
        \toprule
        & Affiliation & Country & Article.No. & TLC & TLC/t & TGC & TGC/t \\  
        \midrule
        1 & World Bank &     USA              & 16 &  61 & 6.28 & 819 & 77.17 \\ 
        2 & Int Monetary Fund &   USA       &3 &  32 & 3.09 & 454 & 35.94 \\  
        3 & Dartmouth Coll & USA            &1 &  29 & 1.61 & 224 & 12.44 \\ 
        4 & Tilburg Univ &     Netherlands  & 2 &  29 & 3.00 & 135 & 12.98 \\
        5 & Wellesley Coll &    USA          &1 &  29 & 1.61 & 224 & 12.44 \\ 
        6 & Univ Amsterdam &   Netherlands   & 2 &  25 & 1.92 & 479 & 38.11 \\
        7 & Univ Kansas &     USA             & 2 &  22 & 2.60 &  56 & 6.61 \\  
        8 & Harvard Univ &   USA           &2 &  17 & 2.05 & 101 & 11.05 \\ 
        9 & Univ Warwick &     UK           &5 &  17 & 1.46 & 128 & 11.68 \\ 
        10 & Univ Copenhagen &   Denmark          &  4 &  16 & 1.93 &  63 & 7.14 \\  
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular*}
    \caption{The most influential affiliations, sorted based on TLC.} %the total number
%   \label{tab:Most-Cited-Affliations}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```