# page width table with a specific column length

Tags: tables, tabularx, xtable

Hello Community, I have a table as follows and I want to set as page width like [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/577647/page-width-table-in-latex/577648#577648) many thanks in advance.
[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,authoryear,sort&compress]{report}
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \usepackage{tabularx}
    \usepackage{geometry}
    
    \begin{document}
    \begin{table}[!ht]
        \centering
        \footnotesize
        \begin{tabularx}{1\textwidth}
            {l
                >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{3cm} 
                c
                >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{7cm} 
                c
                c
                c
                c}
            \toprule  
            & Author(s) Name & Year &  Title & TLC & TLC/t & TGC & TGC/t \\ 
            \midrule    
            1 & Allen F; Demirguc-Kunt A; Klapper L; Peria Msm & 2016 & The Foundations Of Financial Inclusion: Understanding Ownership And Use Of Formal Accounts &  11 & 2.20 &  59 & 11.80 \\ 
            2 & Aterido R; Beck T; Iacovone L & 2013 & Access To Finance In Sub-Saharan Africa: Is There A Gender Gap? &  16 & 2.00 &  54 & 6.75 \\ 
            3 & Claessens S; Feijen E; Laeven L & 2008 & Political Connections And Preferential Access To Finance: The Role Of Campaign Contributions &  25 & 1.92 & 442 & 34.00 \\ 
        
            \midrule 
            & Author(s) Name & Year & Title & TLC & TLC/t & TGC & TGC/t \\ 
            \midrule 
            1 & Claessens S; Feijen E; Laeven L & 2008 & Political Connections And Preferential Access To Finance: The Role Of Campaign Contributions &  25 & 1.92 & 442 & 34.00 \\ 
            2 & Firth M; Lin C; Liu P; Wong Sml & 2009 & Inside The Black Box: Bank Credit Allocation In China's Private Sector &  10 & 0.83 & 166 & 13.83 \\ 
            3 & Cull R; Li W; Sun B; Xu Lc & 2015 & Government Connections And Financial Constraints: Evidence From A Large Representative Sample Of Chinese Firms &   4 & 0.67 &  83 & 13.83 \\  
            \bottomrule%
        \end{tabularx}%
        \caption{The most influential articles, sorted based on TLC/t and TGC/t, respectively.}
        \label{tab:Most-Cited-Papers}
    \end{table}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Replace `>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{7cm} ` with `>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X`. The column will then be narrower, but at least the table fits into the textwidth.

Comment: One of the author names should be "Martinez-Peria M S", not "Peria Msm".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to changing one of the column types from `p{7cm}` to `X`, you may also want to get rid of the whitespace edge along the vertical edges of the table. I would also recommend that you typeset the numbers in the data columns to that their (explicit or implicit) decimal markers are aligned. Oh, and do please fix some of authors' given and family names.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,authoryear,sort&compress]{report}
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \usepackage{tabularx}  % for 'tabularx' env. and 'X' column type
    \usepackage{ragged2e}  % for '\RaggedRight' macro
    \usepackage{siunitx}   % for 'S' column type
    \usepackage{geometry}
    \newlength\mylen
    \settowidth\mylen{Demirguc-Kunt A;}
    
    \begin{document}
    \begin{table}[!ht]
        %\centering % <-- redundant
        \small %\footnotesize
        \begin{tabularx}{1\textwidth}{ @{} 
            l
            >{\RaggedRight}p{\mylen} 
            c
            >{\RaggedRight}X 
            S[table-format=2.0]
            S[table-format=1.2]
            S[table-format=3.0]
            S[table-format=2.2] @{} }
        \toprule  
        & Author Names & Year & Title & {TLC} & {TLC/t} & {TGC} & {TGC/t} \\ 
        \midrule    
        1 & Allen F; Demirguc-Kunt A; Klapper L; Martinez-Peria M S & 2016 
          & The Foundations of Financial Inclusion: Understanding 
            Ownership and Use of Formal Accounts 
          & 11 & 2.20 & 59 & 11.80 \\ 
        2 & Aterido R; Beck T; Iacovone L & 2013 
          & Access to Finance in Sub-Saharan Africa: Is there 
            a Gender Gap? 
          & 16 & 2.00 & 54 & 6.75 \\ 
        3 & Claessens S; Feijen E; Laeven L & 2008 
          & Political Connections and Preferential Access to Finance: 
            The Role of Campaign Contributions 
        & 25 & 1.92 & 442 & 34.00 \\        
        \midrule 
        & Author Names & Year & Title & {TLC} & {TLC/t} & {TGC} & {TGC/t} \\ 
        \midrule 
        1 & Claessens S; Feijen E; Laeven L & 2008 
          & Political Connections and Preferential Access to Finance: 
            The Role of Campaign Contributions 
          & 25 & 1.92 & 442 & 34.00 \\ 
        2 & Firth M; Lin C; Liu P; Wong S M L & 2009 
          & Inside the Black Box: Bank Credit Allocation in China's 
            Private Sector 
          & 10 & 0.83 & 166 & 13.83 \\
        3 & Cull R; Li W; Sun B; Xu L C & 2015 & Government Connections and 
            Financial Constraints: Evidence from a Large Representative 
            Sample of Chinese Firms 
            &  4 & 0.67 & 83 & 13.83 \\  
        \bottomrule
        \end{tabularx}
        \caption{The most influential articles, sorted based on 
                 TLC/t and TGC/t, respectively.}
        \label{tab:Most-Cited-Papers}
    \end{table}
    \end{document}
```